# to compare two text files and output the difference in other file .txt

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to compare two text files and output the difference in other `result.txt`.
I use this command in command prompt:

```
findstr /vixg:Z:\misc\test1.txt Z:\misc\misc\test2.txt > Z:\misc\misc\result.txt
```

But I have the file `result.txt` is the same of `test2.txt`.

Comment: Try adding the `/L` option to `findstr`. Are you aware that this approach only writes those lines to `result.txt` which occur in `test2.txt` and not in `test1.txt`, but not the other way round?

Comment: I try this command findstr /L:Z:\misc\test1.txt Z:\misc\misc\test2.txt > Z:\misc\misc\result.txt. but, not work. thank you

Comment: I meant: instead of `findstr /vixg:...` use `findstr /vixlg:...`

Comment: sorry. I use findstr /vixlg......BUT, not work about my txt files.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? You should provide some sample data ([edit] your post), so others can try to reproduce your issue...

Comment: I have message error :   Unable to read strings of test1.txt

Comment: How are the text file encoded -- ANSI or Unicode? Windows/Mac/Unix?

Comment: encoded -- ANSI  AND  Windows. THANK YOU